# Error Handling Best Practice in IOS Dev

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a preferred way to error handle in ios dev? If so, how should error handling be implemented?

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific. What kind of errors are you talking about?

Comment: use the following snippet to catch errors try{ //your coding} catch (NSException *exception) {//save or initmate user about it} finally { //release the objects} use the following snippet to handle unhandled exceptions globally in appDelegate - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&onUncaughtException); //rest of the coding} void onUncaughtException(NSException* exception){//Save the exception locally so when the app is opened you could get input from user regarding the app crash}

Comment: use @ symbol from before try,catch and finally. FYI:I purposefully left the  @ symbol because when i posted  the try,catch and finally with @ prefix I received following warning "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [documentation on exception handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH13-SW1).

tl;dr Exceptions are only used for unrecoverable errors.  Do not make the mistake of thinking you can take a Java-esque approach to error handling through exceptions.

And here is the [error handling documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) (which is pretty much the same between iOS and Mac OS X).